# ajax запрос на Ссылки с Телефоном

Tags: ajax, post, href

первый раз задаю вопрос, вообще, на форумах.

Проблема в том, что когда я жму на ссылку просто, то на мобильных устройствах он сразу звонит по номеру. Но если я добавлю этой ссылки ajax для передачи данных из формы, то он отправляет данные, но уже не звонит и работает как просто кнопка submit.

В моем случае если я добавлю к ссылки Id="btn", то он отправляет данные, если убрать то звонит. Мне надо чтоб и звонил и отправлял данные

```html
<a   style="color:white" href="tel:8 (702) 800-96-99">
          <u id="btn">+7 747 631 3354</u>
</a>
<form method="post" id="ajax_form" action="" >
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Отправить" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="phonenumber" value="Отправить" /><br>

</form>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(
  function(){
   sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'controllers/controller.php');
   return false; 
  }
 );
});
 
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     "controllers/controller.php", //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
  });
}
```

```html
<a   style="color:white" href="tel:8 (702) 800-96-99">
 <u id="btn">+7 747 631 3354</u>
</a>
 
<form method="post" id="ajax_form" action="" >
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Отправить" /><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="phonenumber" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

Comment: Определиться с методом, или ссылка или форма, что то одно.

Comment: Значит я не могу чтоб он и то и другое делал ?

Comment: Почему нет, из JavaScript вызывать например метод `Location.assign = "tel:123456789";`

Comment: извини, попробовал сделать сам не получилось, такая же проблема как и описал, можешь на основе моего кода показать как правильно

Comment: Убрать ссылку, оставить только `btn`, в [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) добавить метод `.done(function() { Location.href = "tel:123.."; })`

Comment: И при публикации убрать глубоко мысленные комментарии у методов ajax, это лишнее :)

Comment: Все, большое спасибо!!! заработало

Comment: Незачто :) чаще обращайтесь к документации, это сократит время..